# unselect JCheckBox once re-clicked

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I tried a number of other solutions posted on StackExchange but I can't get the JCheckBox to unselect when I click it again [after it's been selected].

I've tried the following and it just stays clicked even when re-clicked:

```
checkbox2.setSelected(false);
    // check state
    //if (checkbox2.isSelected()) {
        // do something...
        checkbox2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // return str;
                    //checkbox = (JCheckBox) event.getSource();
                    if (checkbox2.isSelected()) {
                         checkbox2.setSelected(false);
                        experimentalSelection = "ML";
             System.out.println(experimentalSelection);
                    }

                   }
                  });
```

I assumed that if i added `checkbox2.setSelected(false);` then it would uncheck if it was already selected and then clicked.

Comment: Wait, the JCheckBox should automatically become unselected when you click it in its selected state. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: Maybe you need to tell us more of your story.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  ah ok   thank you. I must have some other thing going on that's making it so it won't deselect when I click it. It might be a grouping that i did earlier in the code...I'll have to check on this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior that you describe -- making the JCheckBox unselected when a user clicks on an already selected JCheckBox is the check box's default/innate behavior. You don't have to do anything special for this to occur, and you certainly don't have to (or want to) change its selection state within a listener. For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GuiFun extends JPanel {
    private JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Foo");

    public GuiFun() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        add(checkbox);
        checkbox.setSelected(false);
        checkbox.addItemListener(l -> {
            if (l.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                System.out.println("CheckBox SELECTED");
            } else {
                System.out.println("CheckBox UNSELECTED");
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GuiFun mainPanel = new GuiFun();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gui Fun");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

}
```